# Part of hover background coming through

Tags: html, css

I have a hover effect that moves a new `background-color` over an existing one, making it appear the background is fading to the right. For some reason a bit of the `background-color` is showing on the left side of the blocks.

The only thing I could think of was my black border, but I have a border set in the elements natural style.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

[image]

```css
#service-tabs-left {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 150px;
}
#service-tabs-right {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 150px;
}

.service-tab-block {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 padding: 1em 25px;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 margin: 30px 0;
 cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #838557;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, #838557 50%);
 background-size: 200% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: bottom right;
 transition:width 0.2s ease;
 -webkit-transition:width 0.2s ease;
}
.service-tab-block.active {
 background: #000;
 color: #FFF;
}

.service-tab-block:hover {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 background-position: bottom left;
 color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="service-tabs-left">
   <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab1">DEMOLITION</h1>
   <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab2">ENVIRONMENTAL SOLUTIONS</h1>
   <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab3">CONCRETE CRUSHING</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="service-tabs-right">
   <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab4">ASSET RECOVERY</h1>
   <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab5">SCRAP METAL RECYCLING</h1>
   <h1 class="service-tab-block" id="service_tab6">FOUNDATION REMOVAL</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: For me it's working well

Comment: @Mojtaba The last three boxes you will see a black border on the left.

Comment: I tried on Chrome and FF. no extra border

Comment: Weird. I get it in the snippet, jsfiddle, Chrome and every browser. I just added an image to my question. You don't see that?

Comment: Believe me. There is no border for me. I wish someone else participates and tries

Comment: @Becky, Mac user, i guess?

Comment: Is your browser zoomed in/out at all? I get the borders when doing so.

Comment: Can be fixed by adding a min-width: 387px; to your service-tab-block class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `background-size` property from 200% to 201%. The extra 1% gives the cover you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/o7sxoton/

Comment: Thanks! this did it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the linear gradient for black to 49% on `.service-tab-block`

BTW , this is one of those issues you can see by adjusting your browsers zoom for anyone who was wondering.

```
.service-tab-block {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 49%, #838557 50%);
```

Comment: I tried this is my fiddle if you change the gradient to 49% the transition no longer completes and you will see some green on the right side of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Set this:

```
.service-tab-block{
     box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```